# How does this randomizer work

Tags: vbscript

I've a piece of code to randomize the order of words in a text file, but I'm not sure exactly what it's doing. Here is the code.

```
 Randomize()

    For count = 1 To 10
        rand = (Int((10 - count + 1) * Rnd() + count))
        temp = words(count)
        words(count) = words(rand)
        words(rand) = temp
    Next
```

Could somebody please explain this to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First impressions... Not very well. Without `Rnd()` being initialised with `Randomise()` the seed will be the same and the likelihood of returning the same values significantly increases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first check [msdn rnd description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e566zd96(v=vs.84).aspx) and note:

> The Rnd function returns a value less than 1 but greater than or equal to 0

and

> To produce random integers in a given range, use this formula: `Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)`

having this in mind, we see next algorithm:

1. set current word index to 1 (first word)
2. pick random index which is equals or greater then current (ie select word from the rest of array)
3. swap current word with randomly picked
4. increase current word index (ie reduce size of unassigned words pool)
5. go to #2

you can also use a little bit different description:

imagine that you have un-ordered set of words, you pick random one, remove it from set and append it to ordered array, so finally you will have randomly ordered array of words from original set

Comment: Useless without the `Randomize()` function call to change the seeded value.

Comment: I had already called this before the code. I probably should have said this beforehand.